# bad line in namelist &ions: " 10 10 1 0 0 0" (error could be in the previous line)

Tags: lattice, conductor, wscf

every one can you help me to solve this problem below.
I try to simulate an input.in file using Quantum expresso, but I find the following error 'bad line in namelist &ions: "    10 10 1 0 0 0" (error could be in the previous line)'.
I wish you help me soon as possible.
Thank you.

```
 &control
     calculation = 'vc-relax'
     restart_mode = 'from_scratch'
     prefix = 'InAs_GaAs'
     pseudo_dir = '/chemin/vers/les/pseudopotentiels'
     outdir = '/chemin/vers/le/répertoire/de/sortie'
     tprnfor = .true.
  /

 &system
     ibrav = 4
     celldm(1) = 20.0
     nat = 2
     ntyp = 2
     ecutwfc = 40
     ecutrho = 320
     occupations = 'smearing'
     smearing = 'gaussian'
     degauss = 0.02
  /

&electrons
    conv_thr = 1.0e-8
    mixing_mode = 'plain'
    mixing_beta = 0.7
    diagonalization = 'david'
/


ATOMIC_SPECIES
    In  114.818  In.pbe-dn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
    As  74.922  As.pbe-dn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
    In  0.0  0.0  0.0
    As  2.75  0.0  0.0

K_POINTS automatic
   10 10 1 0 0 0
```

I try to generate an output file, in order to achieve the results expected to build my project.